# Subversion - nested branches

Tags: svn, merge, nested, branch

I have created a branch Feature1 from trunk. Then I created a branch Feature1.1 from Feature1.
Like this:

```
                      +--------- Feature1.1
                     /
              +-----+----------- Feature1
             /
 /----------+--------------------------------------------- trunk
```

I have now finished my work on Feature1, but I have to do some more coding on Feature1.1, so I have merged Feature1 with trunk like this:

1. Merged: Trunk -> Feature1
2. Merged: Feature1 -> Feature1.1
3. Merged: Feature1 -> Trunk (with reintegrate)

My plan was then to merge "Trunk -> Feature1.1" and continue working in Feature1.1 and bug fixing Feature1 in the trunk. But when I try to merge "Trunk -> Feature1.1" it looks like all the files in the project are marked with conflicts.

Will I have to manually merge the files (~100 files...) or does anyone know how to solve this?

One solution could be to merge the files in Feature1.1 to Feature1 (if even that's possible) and then do another trunk-reintegrate-merge from the Feature1 branch. See chapter [Keeping a Reintegrated Branch Alive](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice) in the SVN book.

Comment: Not sure it will answer your question, but if you were using git, it's very simple. You just rebase branch Feature1.1 against the new trunk. One command. I don't think it's easy in SVN, you could use "git svn" bridge, however you would have difficulties to sync back it into svn. How git does it - it reaaplies diffs made in Feature1.1 on top of the new base (latest trunk in your case).

Comment: Probably it is out of topic but... why don't you switch to a different SCM?

Comment: @pablo : go away - SVN works great for its purpose. Your chosen SCM is not necessarily the best choice for everyone.

Comment: @JoshM. yep, svn is so great that every major oss project abandoned it... back in 2008!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work out of the box. If, as it seems, it doesn't work on your setup, and since you know that every change done on the trunk until the revision reached at step 3 of your scenario (that we'll call *TheRev*), you may merge all the revisions from trunk to Feature1.1 until *TheRev* with the [`--record-only`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.record_only) flag. It will just mark those revisions as merged in Feature1.1.

You should the be able to work as usual.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I wasn't sure if both trunk and branch needed to be synched with each other for record-only to work. You cleared that up for me.